# Encrypting Eureka Server Password

Tags: spring-cloud

Is there a way to encrypt the password. I tried below code but it doesn't work (not using spring-cloud-config).

```
StandardPasswordEncoder encoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder("eurekaserverpassword");
String encryptedValue = encoder.encode("password");
```

The generated password is placed in application.yml

```
security:
  user:
    password: '{cipher}3da45506d8dd45b29d5db2a52c23bd6bc2e129372846cc51cdb8397e2a641eb12dfbc61757ddcf42'
```

And defined the key in bootstrap.yml

```
encrypt:
  key:eurekaserverpassword
```

I'm getting below error

```
UnsupportedOperationException: No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
```

I'm not using asymmetric approach, why it is looking for keystore?

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.eureka</groupId>
  <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.demo.EurekaApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <name>Eureka Server</name>
  <description>Eureka Server</description>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
   </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
   </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                   <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
             </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <requiresUnpack>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
              <artifactId>eureka-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
              <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
          </requiresUnpack>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you have `spring-security-rsa` on your classpath?

Comment: Yes..refer pom.xml added above. Also, I'm not using config-server.

Comment: can you try encrypting using one of the methods here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption

Comment: Tried cloud config but same error..One thing I encountered with cloud config, decrypt throws error 'Text not encrypted with this key' when invoked with same data and secret/key. A verbose documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It got resolved. First, I encrypted my password using config server and then used the key store details from config server (bootstrap.yml) into eureka-server bootstrap.yml.